# React useEffect is not triggered when using filter function while rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my component `JobList` I am displaying a list of Job cards which is loaded in `useEffect` The job list is stored in the state. It works fine if I am displaying the list as is. However if I am filtering jobs based on user search, the state is reset and `useEffect` is not triggered which in turn does not load the job List resulting into error.

Snippet:

```
export default function JobList() {
  const [jobs, setjobs] = useState(initialValues);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // loading the jobs from backend
    const fetchJobs = async () => {
      const jobList = await jobServices.getJobsList();
      setjobs(jobList);
    };
    fetchJobs().catch((error) => handleError(error));
  }, []);

  const keys = [
    "vehicle",
    "customer_mobile"
  ];
  
  // this function is to filter jobs based on user search
  const filteredJobs = (jobs) => {
    return jobs.filter((job) => keys.some((key) => job[key].includes(query)));
  };

 return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <TextField
          label="Search Jobs"
          type="search"
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Container>
      <Container>
        <Grid container spacing={6}>
          {filteredJobs(jobs).map((job) => (
            <Grid key={job.id} item xs={4}>
              <JobCard job={job} handleError={handleError} key={job.id} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

This code works for initial load but after any user action the jobs state is reset and useEffect is not triggered. It works absolutely fine it I do not filter jobs.

If I do (no filtering):

```
<Grid container spacing={6}>
              {jobs.map((job) => (
                <Grid key={job.id} item xs={4}>
                  <JobCard job={job} handleError={handleError} key={job.id} />
                </Grid>
              ))}
            </Grid>
```

Instead of (filtering):

```
<Grid container spacing={6}>
              {filteredJobs(jobs).map((job) => (
                <Grid key={job.id} item xs={4}>
                  <JobCard job={job} handleError={handleError} key={job.id} />
                </Grid>
              ))}
            </Grid>
```

It works as expected.

I am thinking it is due to the way I am calling `filteredJobs` function while rendering.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. I cannot reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, you can improve the filteredJobs function to ensure it shows all jobs when the search bar is empty or the search term doesn't match any jobs.

```
 
const filteredJobs = (jobs) => {
  if (!query) { // Check if the query is empty
    return jobs; // Return all jobs if the query is empty
  }

  return jobs.filter((job) => keys.some((key) => job[key]?.toString().includes(query)));
};
```

Comment: Thanks @dick-larsson it works now. I am a new in React so want to understand what was wrong earlier. I am wondering why was the page loading correctly for the first time (search = "")?  However once I navigate away from page and try to come back, it was throwing null error as jobs state was empty. I can understand it was due to the `filteredJobs` function returning empty list but how did it work in the initial load? because of this behaviour i was focussing on why `useEffect` did not run after initial load.

Answer (score 0):

try these modifications:

1. We are using the hook useMemo to change filteredJobs when just jobs or query changes
2. keys can go outside the component to prevent rerender of the const
3. create a function to handleSearch

```
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";

const keys = ["vehicle", "customer_mobile"];

export default function JobList() {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState(initialValues);
  //my suggestion is to use a hook to debounce the search query
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchJobs = async () => {
      const jobList = await jobServices.getJobsList();
      setJobs(jobList);
    };
    fetchJobs().catch(handleError);
  }, []);

  const filteredJobsMemoized = useMemo(()=>{
      return jobs.filter((job) =>
    keys.some((key) => job[key].includes(query))
  );
  },[jobs,query]);

  function handleSearch(event) {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <TextField label="Search Jobs" type="search" onChange={handleSearch} />
      </Container>
      <Container>
        <Grid container spacing={6}>
          {filteredJobsMemoized.map((job) => (
            <Grid key={job.id} item xs={4}>
              <JobCard job={job} handleError={handleError} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks @mateus-amaral. Interesting solution with `useMemo`  I will give it a try next time. The earlier solution from @dick worked for me.